# Weird bash script anomaly - what is anaconda-ks?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, anaconda

I was trying to write a simple bash script to print a bunch of random characters:

```
for i in {1..100000}
do
    echo -n $(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $(( ( RANDOM % 220 )  + 35 ))))
done
```

It does that all right, but, for some mysterious reason a bunch of not random character shows up:

> DU▒▒2D@I▒▒▒lb;▒.lO▒c▒˕#m~<▒ﭷ▒wp▒▒]▒2▒US`栃y▒)▒▒|▒ߎD▒▒l▒8▒T▒℘6▒wh;▒▒7▒h▒▒ωӕ▒$▒йa▒▒▒▒깅-▒+▒1▒0ıC▒▒▒j1▒▒P.h=fm;▒▒6;;▒▒▒▒kL(%<▒▒o▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒▒5y#▒▒ΖsbA1vi_▒▒b▒▒ظ▒>▒▒k۹▒Ysɂ▒▒▒(▒▒▒G▒Դ▒▒cՋ▒=▒I▒ڰ벫▒l▒P▒▒KԽ▒▒lk▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒-▒ÇR▒▒▒C▒▒+w▒M▒{@س▒▒ǅ▒j'q▒n'▒Tp▒▒lh▒▒.▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒c▒N▒ܳ▒j▒▒▒▒▒▒s@=▒j▒$h▒U▒▒&▒3▒/▒+W▒▒۠^▒▒N)▒oz▒▒▒▒1}΃▒▒▒B4▒▒▒/U▒▒▒▒~▒:▒▒▒▒▒'▒▒.|▒pߺ▒▒+▒c▒▒▒Iɔ▒▒▒▒▒ϞTm&▒▒<Bo&▒т▒▒VH▒2m▒▒;▒O'▒▒؜▒⊞q▒Ǧ▒▒▒O▒▒▒▒틈▒▒▒$ྕ▒▒ф▒ַ▒▒n<6▒▒▒N@f▒▒▒)[▒▒y1'▒n▒UзkB'▒▒]z&u8▒▒D▒▒7_▒▒|\▒▒eEy▒2ʉؕF▒▒zٹ▒)X▒▒▒?▒▒h▒▒l▒▒0▒▒L▒R:▒▒▒X▒▒▒wz▒▒6▒/▒oTڣ3d\n▒7iX`\▒O9>ot▒K▒▒▒▒▒(<▒▒▒▒`▒▒b▒▒;▒l▒▒P▒▒<6▒▒▒▒▒▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒▒r▒>J+`(▒Ч▒)7Yq{el▒▒▒H▒Œ▒t▒gtqanaconda-ks.cfg Desktop Documents
>   Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music Pictures Public
>   Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos8▒ǲ▒A▒y▒0C▒D▒▒▒V▒▒8▒U▒~U▒L▒▒▒h▒}[▒<~▒▒▒{▒>Gf^▒%`d▒▒▒▒▒tq▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒▒▒▒>D▒▒▒▒anaconda-ks.cfg Desktop Documents Downloads
>   install.log install.log.syslog Music Pictures Public Templates
>   timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videok▒r▒&X▒▒▒x▒%▒▒-OՈT▒�D4▒N▒▒▒Q[x▒▒▒▒^▒;▒▒%▒▒▒m~▒▒U▒▒▒▒▒▒Wi▒▒mY▒▒▒o▒▒7W▒e▒▒E▒▒▒+▒ʥ▒▒N▒▒▒:▒▒▒▒Ԙ▒Bғ▒%[C▒▒@x▒Os▒y▒▒▒▒K)A]▒▒¹[.▒0▒▒▒▒1▒T▒▒r#I[Z▒▒▒x▒@▒▒Z▒▒▒W▒?▒rI▒▒▒\▒▒▒,▒▒▒?▒H▒▒+x▒Dm▒π▒>▒_y_H▒▒▒霰J▒▒u▒▒▒▒a▒▒2▒Zc&▒▒▒<▒▒T[쏕▒▒}ʟ▒H½▒r▒Xf▒▒▒Ppq▒U▒▒0▒▒Ҫ▒▒LBy'1ߟ▒▒▒▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒/▒HE▒'▒'▒~▒_¯k▒^▒ܗm▒▒▒▒kj▒▒$▒▒[6▒▒)▒▒▒кb▒▒▒yM{&▒B▒NQv▒▒L▒▒▒Sw▒▒▒j3▒5ǥs▒Rk▒ʓZ▒▒k▒▒banaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒▒t`▒/▒▒-ݯ▒P.▒-,K▒▒▒▒hAn▒▒▒▒[▒3)WJ▒▒▒#▒(▒▒Z%▒+▒ճ▒▒T▒,▒▒▒Ë▒ށӈ▒▒▒j▒▒ԇ▒-?
>   ▒?#▒CHi▒▒4▒xz▒{c▒П▒=▒gsM]▒▒▒_b▒t▒▒5J▒oJ&W▒c▒Ħ▒Gd▒#▒[/WR5▒v▒▒|Jd▒/▒Y▒`d:▒6▒▒}▒▒|g^▒i▒u240b▒▒▒[▒▒A▒p5▒▒Z▒Pr}Ъ▒▒▒▒ғ▒&_b▒▒▒}M▒▒u▒P▒/▒:▒g▒׷▒ta`V`▒9▒▒w\▒▒XS▒▒S▒▒`▒▒▒▒▒▒▒Q▒,Q▒U'▒▒▒▒▒XgX▒▒B▒O▒▒▒▒l▒^▒l_U▒▒U>▒▒▒7X▒)Ԓ`r▒20▒▒'ۇ▒%▒-▒▒7~▒anaconda-ks.cfg
>   Desktop Documents Downloads install.log install.log.syslog Music
>   Pictures Public Templates timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos⟯▒P▒t}|▒V>▒mV▒9▒▒▒▒Danaconda-ks.cfg Desktop Documents Downloads
>   install.log install.log.syslog Music Pictures Public Templates
>   timesynch.err timesynch.log timesynch.sh
>   Videos▒k▒k▒▒▒▒ҋ>▒S:Sb▒Ȣ▒B▒n▒▒@&▒u▒▒▒▒▒˪Oz▒H▒ڳN▒(^▒Fl61▒▒,▒▒i▒=▒E▒1ͳ▒bL-
>   OC▒▒▒,VgI▒▒▒Y▒&▒o▒IaIqp▒t▒▒twJ▒C8{▒▒T▒o▒ۺ▒▒Mx▒g▒Rpm▒Qu▒▒▒▒49\=▒^

So, my question is, what is anaconda-ks, and how and why does it shows up in the output, with all the other stuff?

Comment: Looks like you are somehow managing to execute `ls` in your home directory by the looks of it. `anaconda-ks.cfg` lives there maybe as a hidden file `.anaconda-ks.cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your *unquoted* command substitution produces an `*`, the shell expands it as a pattern that matches every file in your current directory. The simple solution is to quote it.

```
for i in {1..100000}
do
    echo -n "$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $(( ( RANDOM % 220 )  + 35 ))))"
done
```

That said, there is no need to capture the standard output of a command simply to output it again.

```
for i in {1..100000}
do
    printf \\$(printf '%03o' $(( ( RANDOM % 220 )  + 35 )))
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. TIL.